# Mathematica Documentation for HoldAll: Unevaluated doesn't do anything?

Tags: evaluation, hold

I'm trying to understand the difference between `HoldAll` and `Unevaluated`. The documentation for `HoldAll`, under "Application", lists the following example:

```
(* Use HoldAll and Unevaluated to suppress evaluation of symbols wherever it would occur: *)

In[1]:= SetAttributes[symbolLength, HoldAll];
symbolLength[s_Symbol] := StringLength[SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]]]

(* Find the length of a symbol's name even if it has a value: *)

In[2]:= xyzzy = 1;

In[3]:= symbolLength[xyzzy]

Out[3]= 5
```

The problem is that if you define `symbolLength` **without** `Unevaluated`, i.e.

```
symbolLength[s_Symbol] := StringLength[SymbolName[s]]
```

then the function **still** returns 5. So what's the point of `Unevaluated`? Also, more generally, shouldn't `HoldAll` already keep `s` unevaluated? And if that's the case, then is there any reason to combine `HoldAll` and `Unevaluated` in the same function?

Comment: I get an error, not `5`, in the second version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6zUR.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is in what happens if the symbol you are passing in has a value assigned.

```
SetAttributes[symbolLength1, HoldAll];
symbolLength1[s_Symbol] := StringLength[SymbolName[s]]

SetAttributes[symbolLength2, HoldAll];
symbolLength2[s_Symbol] := StringLength[SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]]]
```

```
asd = 1
```

```
In[15]:= symbolLength1[asd]

During evaluation of In[15]:= SymbolName::sym: Argument 1 at position 1 is expected to be a symbol.

During evaluation of In[15]:= StringLength::string: String expected at position 1 in StringLength[SymbolName[1]].

Out[15]= StringLength[SymbolName[1]]

In[16]:= symbolLength2[asd]

Out[16]= 3
```

The role of the `HoldAll` attribute is to ensure that when evaluating `symbolLength2[asd]`, then `asd` does not evaluate before `symbolLength2[...]` does.

The role of `Unevaluated` is to ensure that the evaluation sequence inside of `symbolLength2` will be this:

`SymbolName[Unevaluated[asd]] -> SymbolName[asd] -> "asd"`

And not this:

`SymbolName[asd] -> SymbolName[1] -> error`

`HoldAll` has no impact on what happens to `asd` once it has been substituted into the right-hand-side of `symbolLength2`'s definition. It merely makes it possible to make this substitution without evaluating `asd` first. After this initial substitution, evaluation control is in your hands.

The best tutorial on understanding evaluation control is "Working with Unevaluated Expressions" by Robby Villegas: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/

You may also want to go through the Evaluation of Expressions documentation page, which describes how `Unevaluated` is treated in a non-standard way.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html